# xml display in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I have created xml with XElement, but when I display this on an aspx page the format is not what I would like which is:

[image]

c# code:

```
var persons = new[] {
    new Person {
        Name = "Patrick Hines",
        PhoneNumbers = new[] { "206-555-0144", "425-555-0145" }
    },
    new Person {
        Name = "Gretchen Rivas",
        PhoneNumbers = new[] { "206-555-0163" }
    }
};

XElement contacts = new XElement("contacts",
                        from p in persons
                        select new XElement("contact",
                             new XElement("name", p.Name),
                                 from ph in p.PhoneNumbers
                                 select new XElement("phone", ph)
                              ));

            Response.Write(contacts);
```

> ```
> class Person
> {
>     public string Name;
>     public string[] PhoneNumbers;
> }
> ```

Comment: what are you expecting and what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return an XML document, you will have to change the content-type:

```
  ...
  Response.ContentType = "text/xml"; 
  Response.Write(contacts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead:

```
Response.Write(contacts.ToString());
```